# Firebase real-time database authentication for multiple users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I was looking for simple authentication mechanism for multiple users in Firebase real-time database. For ex: I don't want all millions of users to login using email and password to access Firebase real-time.

I came across creating custom token from the below documentation.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

I want to understand clearly about that. Is this something that helps to authenticate multiple users (grouped as one) programmatically via custom token instead of each user has to authenticate using email address and password? or This is different from what I thought?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

No, custom tokens are used when you have your own database of users that have already signed into your existing service with some other form of credentials that you provide.

If you don't have your own database of users, custom tokens won't help.

Also, there is no such thing as "grouping" users for the purpose of authentication using Firebase Authentication.  Each user has their own distinct identity with their own credentials that are dealt with independently of each other.

Comment: Grouping user meaning, please check "Frank van Puffelen" answer, we can have list of user IDs grouped. Only they are allowed to authenticate and access .

Comment: I am not still getting this -> "custom tokens are used when you have your own database of users that have already signed into your existing service" . What is the difference from Firebase real-time DB service?

Comment: If you don't want to use one of the providers that Firebase Authentication allows (like Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc), you would use custom tokens for that.  That's the only real use for custom tokens.

Comment: So multiple users single way of authentication, can I choose token mechanism instead login with email?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between when a user signs in (authentication) and when they gain access to your database (authorization).

There is no way to prevent users from authenticating with Firebase Authentication's built-in providers that you've enabled in the Firebase console. But it's quite easy to only allow specific users access to the data in your database with Firebase's server-side security rules.

For example, if you only want specific users access, you can set up a whitelist of their UIDs:

```
allowedUsers
  uid1: true,
  uid2: true,
  uid3: true
```

Now you can write a simple security rule that only allows users in this list to read your database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "root.child('allowedUsers').child(auth.uid).exists()"
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! But, what to do when we have millions of users using our App and we want to provide authentication mechanism through Firebase? All the users has to login with one email address and password to authenticate. This is my problem.

Comment: What do these millions of users have in common? If they don't have anything in common, all you can do is enumerate their accounts.

Comment: "There is no way to prevent users from authenticating with Firebase Authentication's built-in providers." This would be true only for the authentication providers you have allowed in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Custom tokens are used when you have your own authentication service but want to allow your users to access Firebase services. If you want your users to be able to use the database without an email and password, you can [use a provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin) such as Google or use [Anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth), which is when the user is logged in and can access the database, but don't have to prove that they're themselves. You can always add them as an actual user later.

To allow authenticated users to access the database, you can use these rules:

```
// These rules require authentication
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

[Database Rules Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart)